# How to refresh configuration variables from package in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

How to refresh configuration variables in /package @ laravel 5.3?
I made

```
php56 artisan config:cache
php56 artisan cache:clear
php56 artisan config:clear
```

All the variables from `/config/*.php` were refreshed
The variables from `/packages/name/reporting/src/config/config.php` were not

Answer (score 0):

firstly you have to publish the package so that it can copy the file to root config directory from vendor package folder. than try to change config. Below is the command to publish the vendor..

php56 artisan vendor:publish --tag=config

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [sandeep-goel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6185266/sandeep-goel)
The problem for me was in the sequence, the correct is:

$ php56 artisan vendor:publish

Copied File [/packages/name/reporting/src/config/config.php] To [/config/config.php]

$ php56 artisan config:cache

Configuration cache cleared!
Configuration cached successfully!